# Keeping login/registration in JS, not razor views when scaffolding Core 3 project with Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-3.0

Also happens with react and scaffolding a new project in VS. Any login/registration uses razor layout/views and everything else uses angulars.

New to angular, but having 2 versions of a sites layout isn't DRY, but with the default scaffolding doing it, I'm guessing there is a reason. Not finding anything as to why or how to convert to use only angular views.

Simple example: If I run the new project and change the login-menu.component.html that was generated to have a red login link. Clicking it will load generated MVC view and it would be changed back to black. I would have to change in both places to keep it red.

Comment: Those aren't 2 versions, It's just one site. A View *renders* HTML and Javascript and sends it to the browser for execution. That Javascript may contain Angular code for execution on the client. Even Angular uses server-side rendering when possible

Comment: Think you misunderstood. JavaScript has nothing to do with the question. Having to The same layout is created by angular and MVC and both are being used by default. So the same changes have to be made to angular's html and MVC's layout html.

Comment: There has to be a solution...Best practice for an angular app with identity and .net core cannot be redirects to razor.

Answer (score 1):

For Asp.Net Core Angualr template with Identity, it is combined with Angular View and Identity Library which is razor view. This is by design.

For Identity, it is developed with Identity Library which is Razor Library.

While clicking the Login link from Angular `login-menu.component.html`, it redirect the page to login page in Identity library.

You need to override the pages in Identity Library to change the login page.

Comment: Correct, it just seems like bad design. Was curious if there were any examples out there to get rid of the razor views without me going through the 50 some odd files to figure out what needs to be changed. Realize this is new, but one can hope.

Comment: Did you get around this, @VirtualLife? It does seem wrong.

Comment: @DirkWessels Nope, had to give up on angular. From what I gathered, you have to re-write/modify all the pre-built code.

Comment: Did you give up on Angular altogether? This is a Visual Studio / Identity problem, not an Angular problem. In another .Net Core 2.2 project I had simply coded the .Net API (still using Identity Server, but without the .Net generated html/javascript ) and Angular frontend separately and used my own code for logging in and passing a JWT token around. Looks like I'll be doing the same with this new project.

Comment: @DirkWessels Realize it's been a while. Yes, gave up on Angular. Built the same project in all 3 frameworks and found Angular to be the most code and hardest to debug. It has some more functionality, but react/vue seemed better overall. Vue was the final choice for its lightweight and simplicity. Agreed tho, this was more of a VS issue that may have gotten better.